# Do webservers have to be publicly accessible for Google Universal Analytics to work?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am using the "Bi-directional cross-domain tracking" script from Google to track visitors on a secondairy domain.

This is the script I am using:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-1', 'auto', { 'allowLinker': true });
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['main.com', 'secondary.com']);
ga('send', 'pageview', window.location.pathname);
```

The script can be found here:
[Analyics.js Linker](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker)

I also made sure both domains were included in the "Referral exclusion list".

I have installed Google Tag Assistant (a Chrome extension), and it works like it's supposed to. I get a green icon, and also the message that 1 request is made. But I don't see any hits in Google Analytics.

I called with Google helpdesk, and only then I realised that 'secondary.com' is a server (used for testing) accessible only on our internal network.

Is that the reason why there are no results in Google Analytics?

**Update**

When we put our code in production we did get results in Google Analytics.

But that does not automatically mean that a server should be publicly accessible for the code to work, because maybe the problem was that the test server was on a sub-domain.

To make things clear we have:

```
companyname.nl (main.com in code)
mycompanyname.nl (secondary.com in code)
test.companyname.nl (the server that is not accessible from the outside)
```

According to the documentation:

> Automatic cookie domain configuration sets the _ga cookie on the highest level domain it can.

So I Assumed `test` subdomain would work too.

I will unaccept the answer from @eike-pierstorff since it's unclear what's really going on.

Comment: It's actually the client that needs access to the internet (to send data to the Google server, and to fetch the analytics.js library).  There is a processing delay, so maybe you did not wait long enough for data to show up ?AFAIK Tag Assistant checks the response for the request to Google, so you would not get a green light if the data weren't send.

Comment: I did wait long enough, several hours in fact, for each attempt in about a week of trying.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question quite literally, no, webservers must not be publicly accessible for Google Universal Analytics to work. The Google Analytics web tracking code does not run on the webserver, in runs in the browser (or other client program). So if the client can access both the internal network and the public internet this should work (

This is more or less the end of the answer, I'll add a few more things in the hope it will help.

For the Google tracking code to work it must be able to set a cookie (or configured with  `'storage': 'none'` and have a client id set by your application), so you'd have to check if your internal url is actually a fully qualified domain name (so js cookies can be set; I'm not sure if secondary.com is just an example or if this is the actual format used in the internal domain name). But even then you should at least see traffic from the public url. The fact that you do not (plus you receive a green light from Tag Assistant) suggests that the problem is not at the collection end.

Did you by chance set up any filters that might affect the way data is collected ? In particular include filters are tricky (since they delete all data that doesn't match a pattern, so if the pattern is wrong they delete everything). If you haven't done it yet create a view without any filters to always have a backup of your data when a filter is misconfigured.

Since you mentioned these in the posts, neither the referral exclusion list nor the linker are likely to have anything to do with your problem; the first maintains the original channel attribution when people switch between domains, the second adds a parameter to links and form actions that allows the other domain to pick up the client id and thus continue the session. The worst that could happen is that cross domain tracking does not work, but sessions on both domains would still be (separately) tracked.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up. Thanks also for the additional information. Altough this just confirms my own ideas and I am still lost why it doesn't show up, even though Google Tag Assistant says it's all fine.